# Unable to plot after running keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I created a simple network with 1 hidden layer. I am able to run the model but after running I am no longer able to plot. Something as simple as plt.plot([1,2,3]) no longer shows and just freezes my jupyter notebook.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model

x = Input(shape=(13,))
h = Dense(units= 3, activation = 'relu')(x)
y = Dense(units=1,activation= None)(h)
model = Model(x, y)

model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train,
validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
batch_size=16,
epochs=50)
```

The above works fine, but when trying to now do

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([2,3,4,5])
```

for example, my code notebook freezes and I have to restart the kernel. This is very odd and I cannot find anyone having a similar problem. I tried uninstalling keras and reinstalling to no avail.

If relevant, when import keras I get

```
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
```

from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Using TensorFlow backend.